# Best way to update a variable in another controller in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller (call it "A") where I get a value from the webserver. When I get this value, I store it in a Service.

In another controller (call it "B") I have to get this value from the service everytime it is stored in the service. And this value must appear in the view (updated).

My usual solution is:
I emit an event everytime I store the value in the service. then in the controller B I listen to this event and then i get the value from the service.

I know there are other solutions, like the scope.$watch/apply but I don't know which is better.

Can you suggest me which way is better?

Answer (score 1):

## Push Values from a Service with [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js)

One alterantive to `$rootScope.broadcast` is to build a service with [RxJS Extensions for Angular](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js):

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx-angular/dist/rx.angular.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['rx']);

app.factory("DataService", function(rx) {
  var subject = new rx.Subject(); 
  var data = "Initial";
  
  return {
      set: function set(d){
        data = d;
        subject.onNext(d);
      },
      get: function get() {
        return data;
      },
      subscribe: function (o) {
         return subject.subscribe(o);
      }
  };
});
```

Then simply subscribe to the changes.

```
app.controller('displayCtrl', function(DataService) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.data = DataService.get();
  var subscription = DataService.subscribe(function onNext(d) {
      $ctrl.data = d;
  });

  this.$onDestroy = function() {
      subscription.dispose();
  };
});
```

Clients can subscribe to changes with `DataService.subscribe` and producers can push changes with `DataService.set`.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/YVKGhCx0DrzyzckMDjtv?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Watchers are called everytime a `$digest` or an `$apply` cycle is done. It has more impact on your application than a local event like you are doing.

If you can use services to control communication between directives and/or controllers, it's better.

As far as i know, there's 4 ways to handle communication between controller and/or directives:

- Using a service (like you do)
- Rely on the `$apply` cycle with `$watch`
- Use the angular event system (with `scope.$emit` or `scope.$broadcast`)
- Be very dirty and use a global variable

Using a service is the best way. Especially if you handle a "one-to-one" communication.

Comment: So the way I'm using (event + service) is the best way to pass and update data between controllers?

Comment: The difference between the first and the third is that the third pass the data inside the event?

Comment: Some tutorials use the service in combination of the $watch, but why they don't mention events with services?

Comment: Because service are just object. They don't have a scope and they can't use the angular event system.

Comment: But is right to store value in the service, then launch the event "valueStored", then catch the event in the other controller and get the value from the service?